# Google play integration error in test environment "there are no accepted cards available for use with this merchant"

Tags: android, google-pay

I'm trying to integrate Google pay wallet following this demo https://github.com/google-pay/android-quickstart.
but when i try to make the payment for testing environment it gives me and error "there are no accepted cards available for use with this merchant".

i provide the below configration's

```
val SUPPORTED_NETWORKS = listOf(
            "AMEX",
            "DISCOVER",
            "JCB",
            "MASTERCARD",
            "VISA")

    /**
     * The Google Pay API may return cards on file on Google.com (PAN_ONLY) and/or a device token on
     * an Android device authenticated with a 3-D Secure cryptogram (CRYPTOGRAM_3DS).
     *
     * @value #SUPPORTED_METHODS
     */
    val SUPPORTED_METHODS = listOf(
            "PAN_ONLY",
            "CRYPTOGRAM_3DS")
```

and the merchant config is

```
val PAYMENT_GATEWAY_TOKENIZATION_PARAMETERS = mapOf(
            "gateway" to PAYMENT_GATEWAY_TOKENIZATION_NAME,
            "gatewayMerchantId" to "exampleGatewayMerchantId"
    )
```

use environment as

```
const val PAYMENTS_ENVIRONMENT = WalletConstants.ENVIRONMENT_TEST
```

i'm using it in india (as i have Indian gmail account) but the issue is how will i be able to add testing cards to my account.

Comment: Any luck to solve this problem?

Comment: Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you determined a gateway but your ID is still "example"

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible reasons for this is that the merchant is requesting payment methods from a user that isn't available in their country.

In this case, you mentioned that you are using an Indian Google account which doesn't support credit card payment methods.

One work-around for this is to create separate Google account for a country that is supported (e.g. the United States) and test using that account.